# discount on total price before checkout in woocommerce when user shares on facebook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I am using wordpress + woocommerce for my site. I want to apply a discount on total price of items in cart before checkout and update the cart total after discount. I want this to be done when user shares this purchase on his wall. Please help me in this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a nifty plugin that does what you need:  Viral Coupon Plugin http://wpin.me/best-ever-plugin-for-woocommerce-say-hello-to-viral-coupon/

I bought it for a customer and it works as expected.  After configuration, I only had to customize the look via CSS.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But is there anyway to apply discount by using woocommerce functions. Because we need to enter the coupon code to apply discount. I want when user shares , discount applies automatically no need to enter the coupon .

Comment: I think the plugin does it automatically, just like you want. User shares when seeing his cart page (just before paying), then the page reloads with the discount calculated. Ask the developer just to be sure, but if i remember well that's what it does.

Comment: I did not use plugin. I did it using hooks and functions of woocommerce.

Comment: Would be good that you publish your solution and accept it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Just check this website, you can find what you are looking for.
http://shareyourcart.com/?v=july

Or you can directly download it here for free
http://wordpress.org/plugins/shareyourcart/